Set chunk sizes in Nuxt3
How to set chunk sizes in Nuxt3?
I have tried to set minSize and maxSize in the 'build' property of the config file but it had no effect at all to the built chunks:
build: {
        publicPath: '/_nuxt/',
        standalone: true,
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [],
        transpile: ['vuetify', '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'],
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                automaticNameDelimiter: '.',
                name: undefined,
                minSize: 30000, 
                maxSize: 500000, 
            }
        },
        html: {
            minify: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                decodeEntities: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                processConditionalComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                trimCustomFragments: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }
        }
    },


Give a read to a few issues like this one: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/9440
